# key property .notif is unknown

Tags: key-value, l3keys

Following the example in The LaTeX Companion, 3rd edition, Part II, page 700, I'm trying the following .sty file and .tex file that loads it, but I get error:

```
./myfont.sty:8: LaTeX Error: The key property '.notif' is uknknown.
```

What's wrong?

```
% myfont.sty
\ProvidesPackage{myfont}[2023-09-14]

\DeclareKeys {
    draft.if        =   @fnt@draft  ,
    final.notif     =   @fnt@draft  ,
    languages.store =   @fnt@foreigns, 
    }
\ProcessKeyOptions[fnt]

\endinput

% driver.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[final,languages={french,russian}]{myfont}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

I'm using pdfTeX and LaTeX <2023-06-01> patche level 1, and L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>.

Comment: Try `final.ifnot` instead of `final.notif`. See the `clsguide`, section 4.4. And AFAIK you should remove the optional argument of `\ProcessKeyOptions` (or define it also for `\DeclareKeys`).

Comment: Typo in TLC3! An errata is needed.

Comment: @egreg but also in ltkeys.dtx. The changes entry says `% \changes{v1.0i}{2022/06/22} {Add \texttt.{.notif} property}` ;-(

Comment: BTW: AFAIK it should be `language.store=\@fnt@foreigns` instead of `languages.store =   @fnt@foreigns`.

Comment: Erratum in TLC: sigh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with the example. First of all, it must be `.ifnot` instead of `.notif`. Second, `.store` expects a macro not the name of a macro. Third, you are declaring the keys without optional family. So the default family `\@currname` is used, which is `myfont` in the example. But `\ProcessKeyOptions` uses the explicit used family `fnt` of the optional argument. So all declared options are unknown for this family. A correct example would be:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myfont.sty}
% myfont.sty
\ProvidesPackage{myfont}[2023-09-14]

\DeclareKeys {
    draft.if        =   @fnt@draft  ,
    final.ifnot     =   @fnt@draft  ,
    languages.store =   \@fnt@foreigns, 
    }
\ProcessKeyOptions

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
% driver.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[final,languages={french,russian}]{myfont}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
This is \if@fnt@draft\else not \fi a draft. Languages are \@fnt@foreigns.

\end{document}
```

[image]
See also section 4.4 of [LaTeX for package and class authors](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf).

Comment: Thak you not just for the corrections but also the explanations.